# Overlapping pattern matches

Tags: haskell, ghc, overlapping-matches

I have the following code:

```
test :: String -> Bool
test "g" = True
test "global" = True
test _ = False
```

When I load it into GHCi (7.0.3), I get:

```
Warning: Pattern match(es) are overlapped
         In an equation for `test': test "g" = ...
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something here?

The following hold:

```
test "" == False
test "g" == True
test "gl" == False
test "global" == True
test "globalx" == False
```

---

UPDATE:

I am using `{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is [GHC bug #5117](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/5117), arising from the use of the `OverloadedStrings` extension. It should be fixed in GHC 7.2.

As a workaround, you could turn off `OverloadedStrings` for the module with `{-# LANGUAGE NoOverloadedStrings #-}`, or turn off the warning with `{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-warn-overlapping-patterns #-}`. Or just ignore it :)

Answer (score 3):

Have you turned on `OverloadedStrings`? If I remember correctly, that causes 'spurious' overlapping patterns warnings, because in that case it's not clear that e.g. "g" and "global" are mutually exclusive.